# How do these Android location options affect the LocationManager isProividerEnabled method?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I'm trying to figure out the location services options under Android 2.3.3 on my Verizon Droid X, I have 3 options:

- Google location services
- Standalone GPS services
- VZW location services

Enabling or disabling **Google location services** causes the following to return true or false respectivly.

```
myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

Enabling or disabling **Standalone GPS services** causes the following to return true or false respectivly.

```
myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

Enabling or disabling **VZW location services** seems to have no affect on the *isProviderEnabled* method. If this option is the only one enabled, then the *isProviderEnabled* method always returns false regardless if using NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER.

The way I understand this is:

- Google location services = WiFi MACID location
- Standalone GPS services = GPS location
- VZW location services = nothing except something special to Verizon (like Navigator)

Is this assumption correct? If so, where does AGPS and CellID come into play?

Answer (score 0):

"Each kind of location service is being used not only to help their applications bring you the most relavent information, but to assist the network in improvements based on your individual experience.

Google wants to know where you are to answer your questions of 'Coffee shops near my location' and various other things.

Verizon uses your path from tower to tower to tower as you travel to make someone else's (or your) trips through the same area more efficient. If while driving up a highway you are on tower A and tower B, C, and D are all coming in to range, but your phone always goes for C...in the future, tower A can just tell your phone to look for tower C rather than have it search blindly.

There's a lot more detail behind the scenes, but that's the general idea."

see reference link below for more details

http://www.droidforums.net/forum/motorola-droid-x2/159360-location-security-settings-questions.html